WSL Access denied
All the people in my dev team and myself have been experiencing a big issue with WSL since a week.
Whenever we try to launch WSL, we get:
Access is denied.

[process exited with code 1 (0x00000001)]
You can now close this terminal with Ctrl+D, or press Enter to restart.

We have the same error message whether we launch an Ubuntu or Debian session, even as Administrator.
When we try to run wsl from Powershell as Administrator, it is the same:
PS C:\Users\<myuser>> wsl
Access is denied.

Of course we all restarted our computers, we tried to catch specific errors but nothing worked...
Do you have any idea guys?
It's most probably an issue with Azure / Windows update.
Windows version: 10 / 11 (we had the same bug on both OS versions)
WSL version: 2.2.4.0

which version of wsl are you using ??

I edited my question, it's WSL 2.2.4.0.
Actually I posted this message so that people having the same issue can possibly find a rapid solution. I already had the answer and it does not seem to depend on Windows / WSL version

Actually as I was asking this questions our IT engineer found a solution.
If this happens to you, launch Powershell as Admnistrator and run:
Add-MpPreference -AttackSurfaceReductionOnlyExclusions "C:\windows\system32\wsl.exe"
Add-MpPreference -AttackSurfaceReductionOnlyExclusions "C:\Program Files\WSL\wsl.exe"

It automatically solved the problem, without having the restart the PC.
The problem is due to an issue with a recent update of Defender
